# Why Chrome is operating disk at a speed of several megabytes per second?

Tags: google-chrome, performance

I found that Chrome is reading disk at speed of several megabytes per second:

[image]

What does it read at my disk?

Comment: Since when was less the 2 megabytes several megabytes?

Comment: follow this (http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60) and give me the ETL file. With it I can see which File and DISK IO Chrome does.

Comment: not interested in getting an answer or why don't you provide the xperf trace?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how many tabs you have, what's in the tabs, and if you have any extensions installed that run constantly. You can see what's running within chrome by Pressing Shift+Esc while the Chrome window is selected, or right clicking on the top bar (not a tab) and selecting task manager. It will show tabs, extensions, and other statistics that effect performance. Hope this helps.